# childViewController not getting deallocated after removing from parentViewController

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, ios5

I'm adding a child view controller as follows:

```
loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    loginViewController.delegate = self;

[self addChildViewController:loginViewController];
[self.view addSubview:loginViewController.view];
loginViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[loginViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

And removing it as follows:

```
[loginViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[loginViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[loginViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

If I understand correctly that should trigger dealloc in LoginViewController but it does not ? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you happen to fix your problem?

Comment: @jbouaziz I don't remember how the issue was resolved but yeah I did reach a conclusion on this

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Removing the controller's view has nothing to do with the controller being released, just the controller's view (which is retained by the controller, so it's not deallocated.

You have `[self addChildViewController:loginViewController];`, are you storing it somewhere? perhaps an array? If that's the case, there's your leak. You need to remove it from wherever you put it